# PHP ftp_nlist is not working

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ftp

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");

if (@ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass))
{
    $path = "./";
    $path1="./test";
    $file = "test.txt";
    $file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn,$path);
}
// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

The above is the code which I am using. It is working fine for me on my Windows local machine, Windows server machine, Linux local machine, but somehow it fails on the Linux server machine. `ftp_nlist` returns `false`. Can someone tell me what might be the reason?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Start by removing all @ (suppression) operators, add ini_set('display_errors', true) and error_reporting(E_ALL) on top of your script.
Any exceptions should be try/catched if you want a robust script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most typical cause of problems with `ftp_nlist` (or any other transfer command like `ftp_get`, `ftp_put`, `ftp_rawlist`) is that PHP defaults to the FTP active mode. And in 99% cases, one has to switch to the FTP passive mode, to make the transfer working. Use the [`ftp_pasv` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php).

```
$connect = ftp_connect($ftp) or die("Unable to connect to host");
ftp_login($connect, $username, $pwd) or die("Authorization failed");
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($connect, true) or die("Passive mode failed");
```

See also *my* article on the [active and passive FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

---

Further, if your FTP server is reporting an incorrect IP address in the response to the `PASV` command, you might need to workaround it by using:

```
ftp_set_option($connect, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
```

See [PHP FTP + Passive FTP Server Behind NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38982901/850848).

*Though the right solution in this case, is to get the server fixed.*

---

*If none of this help, make sure you have tested, if you can even retrieve the directory listing using any commandline/GUI FTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code. You might not have a programming question in the first place.*