# Setting up an ftp_get

Tags: php, ftp, connection

i am attempting to setup a script that connects to an FTP and downloads a file, i used the most basic code:

```
 <?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$local_file = "local.zip";
$server_file = "server.zip";

// download server file
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

When run on my local machine its connects gets the files, but if i try to set the script up on a different FTP to run in on, it crashes out with no error at step: ftp_get
What am i doing wrong here?
Strangest part is it was working at some point, so im pretty sure the approach should work

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49402376/850848

Comment: If the above answer is not the solution, I would check that the server has the FTP extension installed. If your server is Windows and PHP7 - its not enabled by default.

Comment: @Chris It would fail straight at `ftp_connect` then, not only at `ftp_get`.

Comment: Ah I missed that bit. I thought he said "it just crashed out with no error..."